# Enum literal types

Tags: typescript

According to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7642 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/9407 enum literal types should work, but I stumbled across weird problem:

```
const enum STATUS {
    CREATED = 201,
    NOT_FOUND = 404,
}

const statusCode: STATUS.CREATED = 404; // not an error
```

Is it possible to use enum members like this?

ts version: 2.3

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use enum members like this?

No. The reason for the error is that numbers are compatible (assignable) with enums. ie.

```
const enum STATUS {
    CREATED = 201,
    NOT_FOUND = 404,
}


const why: STATUS.CREATED = 123123; // not an error

const foo: 1 = 1;
const because: STATUS.CREATED = foo;
```

In other words its not an error cause this isn't something covered by current TypeScript language design.